# how to open the options window for extraPutty session manager

Tags: putty, serial-port, session

I'm using ExtraPutty and have also installed 'Putty session manager' the session manager's options window:

[image]

It appeared once when I first installed the session manager but I only get access to the sessions ever since. How can I reach the options window from the sessions window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have started the Sessions Manager (likely at C:\Program Files\ExtraPuTTY\Bin\SessionsManager\PuTTYSessionManager.exe), you can **right click on the SessionsManager icon and chose "Options"**:

[image]